# Whats wrong with this javascript object-literal notation?

Tags: javascript, scope, encapsulation, object-literal

I'm trying to implement a .js file for my website considering the holy global namespace. This time I want to do it the right way so please help me with this maybe too easy question:

What I have so far:

```
var myJSFile = (function () {

  function a (){
  } 
  function b (){   
  }

  return {
    global1 : 0,
    global2 : 0,             

    functionc :  function (){
      a();
    },

    functiond : function () {
      a();
      b();
    }
  }; 
})();
```

You see I want to have one global variable "*myJSFile*" to be shown to the global scope. There're also two private functions (*a,b*), two global variables (*global1, global2*) and two global functions (*functionc, functiond*).
This code does work, sure but netbeans seems to **not** like it.
The only thing, **netbeans shows me in its navigator**, is the global variable "myJSFile". No private, no public functions, no other variables. And I really need that, because there will be a ton of functions.

This makes me think, I'm doing something completely wrong. So please give me some advise on how to fix this code and being a better js-programmer.

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT:
I know, how to handle this object and using it like:

```
myJSFile.global1 = anything;
myJSFile.functionc();
```

The problem for me here is the navigator in netbeans which makes me think that I'm doing something wrong by showing nothing to me.

EDIT (II):
Seems like netbeans got updated. Now it's able to recognize the functions and so on.

Comment: Looks fine. Blame NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an object. So your 'public' functions will be properties of the `myJSFile` object. So the following should work:

```
// Public functions
myJSFile.functionc(); // calls a()
myJSFile.functiond(); // calls a() then b()


// Public properties
myJSFile.global1; // 0
myJSFile.global2; // 0
```

This is an example of the `module` pattern. You can read more about that [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but handling this object is clear to me. I edited my question to make my point more clear.